# Proof for discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am struggling with understanding this proof. It was on one of my tests and I am lost on how to prove it.

Prove: For any two real numbers that are not equal, you can find a real number between them.

Comment: I don't know if this is too easy of a proof. But you can always consider the average of two real numbers.

Comment: how about the midpoint?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** if $a<b$, then
$$
\frac{a+b}{2} = a + \frac{b - a}{2} = b - \frac{b - a}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a < b$. The number $c = (a + b)/2$ satisfies $a < c < b$. Indeed:
$$
c = \dfrac{a + b}{2} < \dfrac{b + b}{2} = b
$$
and
$$
c = \dfrac{a + b}{2} > \dfrac{a + a}{2} = a
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x,y,z \in R$

Such that

$x<y<z$

Then $ y=\frac{x+z}{2}$

Thus $x<\frac{x+z}{2}<z$

Comment: If $x < y < z$, does it really follow that $y = \frac{x+z}{2}$?